# Como passar varivlle de um arquivo PHP para outro arquivo PHP

Tags: php, variáveis

Tenho um script que gera um arquivo em pdf. O nome do arquivo é definido no MergePdf.class.php

Mas eu queria que fosse definido no arquivo de origem (variável $nomearquivo), onde ele chama esse php, que é abaixo:

```
//destination path for the User PDF file:
$nomearquivo = 'teste';
$pdfUserfile = JPATH_SITE.'/pdf/pdf-padrao1.pdf';
copy($pdfUser,$pdfUserfile);
require_once("/home/site/public_html/scripts/pdf/MergePdf.class.php");
MergePdf::merge(
    Array(
        $pdfUserfile,
         $arquivoiptu
    ),
    MergePdf::DESTINATION__DISK_INLINE
);
```

Aí precisaria passar esse $nomearquivo para o MergePdf.class.php, mas não sei como fazer.

Comment: Tem muitas respostas no site que tratam disso, inclusive uma (que ainda não linkei acima) que é exatamente o que foi resposndido na sua (de usar include/require); Sugiro uma pesquisa no topo do site. À medida que eu encontrar outros links vinculo na sua pergunta também. Ajudaria se você clicasse em [edit] e explicasse um pouco melhor para que precisa disso, aí talvez dê para apontar para o caminho mais eficiente para o seu caso.

Answer (score 0):

usa o include no arquivo que você quer usar a variavel.

exemplo:
arquivoOrigem.php

echo $nomearquivo;

//o resultado deve ser 'teste' que esta definido no arquivo 'MergePdf.class.php'

Answer (score 0):

Para usar uma variável definida em outro arquivo no arquivo atual, deve-se usar a declaração ***include***.

- [PHP: include - Manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.include.php)

## Exemplo de uso da declaração

*arquivo1.php*

```
<?php 
  $primeiroNumero = 1;
?>
```

*arquivo2.php*

```
<?php 
  include 'arquivo1.php';
  $segundoNumero = 2;

  $soma = $primeiroNumero + $segundoNumero;
  echo $soma; //Mostrará a soma 1+2 = 3
?>
```